# Python json issue - camel case and double quotes

Tags: python, json, csv

I have to read a csv file and create a JSON list out of it. Currently , I first read each row, add to list and use JSON dumps to create the JSON output. There are 2 issues I am facing

1. JSON dumps adds single quotes to the attributes which is not what I want . I wanted each key-value pair to be enclosed in its own double quotes.
2. It is using the CSV file headers for the keys which are not in camel case but I need them in camel case

This is what my program produces

```
{
"Reqlist":[
    {
        'FieldName1' : 'val1'       
    },
    {
        'Fieldname2' : 'val2'
    }
    ],
    
    'metaData' : 'metaVal'
}



This is the output I expect 

{
"Reqlist":[
    {
        "fieldName1" : "val1"       
    },
    {
        "fieldName2" : "val2"
    }
    ],
    
    "metaData" : "metaVal"
}
```

Sample code :

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_data), restkey='INVALID', restval='INVALID')
        headers = reader.fieldnames
        error_count = 0
        success_count =0
        dict=[]
        header_count = set(headers)
        json_error_data = json.dumps({})
        csv_list =[]
        error_list={}
        myDict =[] 
        print(headers)
        if(len(header_count)!=constants.EXPECTED_HEADER_COUNT or (set(headers)!=set(constants.FIELD_NAMES))):
            print('error for record')
        else:
            for row in reader:
                if('INVALID' in row.values()):
                    error_count +=1
                else:
                    success_count +=1
                    csv_list.append(row)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('error')

    if(error_count>0 and success_count == 0 ):
        print('save the errors')
    elif(success_count>0):
        jsonlist = json.dumps({'Reqlist': csv_list })
        new = json.loads(jsonlist)
        a_dict = {'metaData': 'metaVal'}
        new.update(a_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_to_camel(dict1):
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        key = key[0].lower() + key[1:]

        value = value if type(value) is not dict else convert_to_camel(value)
        new_dict[key] = value
    return new_dict

csv_list = [convert_to_camel(i) for i in csv_list]
```

This should work for camel case

For single quote thing, i have written a json-like library for python. It's not perfect, but [here](https://github.com/tunapro1234/DBEX) it is.